# ffmpeg streaming to rtmp and extracting image periodically

Tags: video, ffmpeg, audio, streaming

I'm using this command to receive a input stream and transcode it to a different resolution and stream it to ustream.

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel info -progress /tmp/ffmpeg.log -i udp://10.0.0.150:8181?listen \
-framerate 30 -video_size 1080x720 -vcodec libx264 -b:v 768k -crf 23 -preset medium -maxrate 800k -bufsize 800k \
-vf "scale=640:-1,format=yuv420p" -g 60 -c:a aac -strict -3 -ar 44100 -ab 32k -f flv rtmp://<ustream url>/<ustream key>
```

I also want to extract a full quality snapshot every 1 minute. I read [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20thumbnail%20image%20every%20X%20seconds%20of%20the%20video) how I can extract a thumbnail from a video periodically and I read [this](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Creating%20multiple%20outputs) explaining how to send one input stream to different output streams with different video filters.

When I combined the two commands I ended up with this:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel info -progress /tmp/ffmpeg.log -i udp://10.0.0.150:8181?listen -filter_complex '[0]split=2[in1][in2];[in1]scale=640:-1,format=yuv420p[out1];[in2]fps=1/60[out2]' \
-map '[out1]' -framerate 30 -video_size 1080x720 -vcodec libx264 -b:v 768k -crf 23 -preset medium -maxrate 800k -bufsize 800k -g 60 -c:a aac -strict -3 -ar 44100 -ab 32k -f flv rtmp://<ustream url>/<ustream key> \
-map '[out2]' img%03d.jpg
```

The command almost works, but the audio is missing on the livestream. The images are created correctly and the video is fine but there is no audio. How can I also get audio in my livestream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel info -progress /tmp/ffmpeg.log -i udp://10.0.0.150:8181?listen -filter_complex '[0:v]split=2[in1][in2];[in1]scale=640:-1,format=yuv420p[out1];[in2]fps=1/60[out2]' \
-map '[out1]' -map 0:a -framerate 30 -video_size 1080x720 -vcodec libx264 -b:v 768k -crf 23 -preset medium -maxrate 800k -bufsize 800k -g 60 -c:a aac -strict -3 -ar 44100 -ab 32k -f flv rtmp://<ustream url>/<ustream key> \
-map '[out2]' img%03d.jpg
```

Comment: "Output with label '0:a' does not exist in any defined filter graph, or was used elsewhere"

Comment: Try revised command.